# How does pickle find attributes when loading?

Tags: python, scope, pickle

I don't understand how pickle finds its attributes when loading a file. I would like to provide pickle with different class definitions in different modules, but it's not working for me.

Here is an example.

```
# mod_a.py
import pickle

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_a = True
        
#------------------------------------------------------------------     
def load(file):
    print('Unpickle',repr(A))
    return pickle.load(file)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a pickle file
    a = A()
    with open('a.ar','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,protocol=2)
```

and

```
# mod_b.py
import pickle

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_b = True
        
#------------------------------------------------------------------     
def load(file):
    print('Unpickle',repr(A))
    return pickle.load(file)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a pickle file    
    a = A()
    with open('b.ar','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,protocol=2)
```

and finally

```
import mod_a
import mod_b
 
# from mod_a import A 
# from mod_b import A 

with open('a.ar','rb') as f:
    print(mod_a.load(f))
```

I first create the files `a.ar` and `b.ar`, then run `mod_c.py`, which gives me this error:

```
Unpickle <class 'mod_a.A'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\proj_py\GTC3\tmp\mod_c.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(mod_a.load(f))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\proj_py\GTC3\tmp\mod_a.py", line 10, in load
    return pickle.load(file)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'A' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\proj_py\\GTC3\\tmp\\mod_c.py'>
```

I had expected that pickle would find the definition of `A` in the module where `load()` is defined, which the print() statement shows. However, that doesn't happen.

To overcome the error, I can uncomment one of the import statements in `mod_c.py`. For example, if I use`from mod_b import A`  then the class A defined in `mod_b` is restored, which is not what I intend b calling `mod_a.load(f)`.

Can I modify `mod_a` and `mod_b` so that their `load()` functions restore the class in their respective modules?

EDIT: -------------------------
Following @KamilCuk 's hint the following modified files seem to do the trick.

```
# mod_a.py
import pickle
import sys

class _Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if hasattr(sys.modules[__name__],name):
            return getattr(sys.modules[__name__],name)
        else:
            return super(_Unpickler,self).find_class(module, name)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_a = True
        
def load(file):
    return _Unpickler(file).load()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    a = A()
    with open('a.ar','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,protocol=2)
```

and

```
# mod_b.py
import pickle
import sys

class _Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if hasattr(sys.modules[__name__],name):
            return getattr(sys.modules[__name__],name)
        else:
            return super(_Unpickler,self).find_class(module, name)
            
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_b = True
        
def load(file):
    return _Unpickler(file).load()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    a = A()
    with open('b.ar','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,protocol=2)
```

with

```
# mod_c.py
import mod_a
import mod_b

with open('a.ar','rb') as f:
    print( mod_a.load(f) )
    # print( mod_b.load(f) )
```

Now `mod_a.load(f)` unpickles the `mod_a` version and `mod_b.load(f)` unpickles the `mod_b` version.

(Of course, this does not necessarily unpickle the object using the initial definition of `A` -- I don't think a pickle file records enough infrmation to do that. What this code does do is make clear the particular definition of `A` that is used.)

Comment: You might be interested in https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler.find_class . The main class python runs is `__main__`

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, that is definitely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I entered as an update to my question is working well for me, so I am proposing it as the answer.

Each module needs to follow this pattern

```
# mod_a.py 

import pickle
import sys

class _Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if hasattr(sys.modules[__name__],name):
            return getattr(sys.modules[__name__],name)
        else:
            return super(_Unpickler,self).find_class(module, name)
            
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_b = True
        
def load(file):
    return _Unpickler(file).load()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    a = A()
    with open('b.ar','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f,protocol=2)
```

In this way, client code has control over the module that is searched, like this:

```
import mod_a

with open('a.ar','rb') as f:
    print( mod_a.load(f) )
```